# I always get: "Invalid appsecret_proof provided"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I know that in the last update of Facebook API, there exists the possibility of provide a `appsecret_proof` that is the access token signed with the app_secret.

Now the problem is that, irregardless of the option that I set on my facebook app (enable\disable : `Require AppSecret Proof for Server API calls`) I always get:

`Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument`

I discovered that last version of php-facebook-sdk always inserts between parameters `appsecret_proof`

```
...
if (isset($params['access_token'])) {
    $params['appsecret_proof'] = $this->getAppSecretProof($params['access_token']);
}
...
protected function getAppSecretProof($access_token) {
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $this->getAppSecret());
}
...
```

If I disable the check on my app, and comment the line that inserts the parameter, everything works fine, otherwise I get the error.

Now, where am I wrong?
I triple checked `$access_token`, `$this->getAppSecret()` and the doc, all seem correct.
Any clues?

Comment: Are you using the wrong app ID, wrong app secret, or trying to use an Access Token from the wrong app?

Comment: Yeah.. the AccessToken was correct, but was an old token for an old app.. Thank you! I will delete this question tomorrow, because it's very useless. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Put your mind to work from the easy to the complex solutions of a problem. In this specific case, what I would first do is double (triple) check my: **App-ID**, **App-Secret**, **API-Version** (all 3 provided in the App Dashboard) and **Access token** (Tools & Support > Graph API Explorer).

For me the missing part was the access token. Make sure that under Graph API Explorer, find the dropdown on the right and **choose your registered application name**, instead of the default value of "Graph API Explorer".

So after all your code should look like this (Graph v2.4):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => $api_version
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was finally able to get rid of the error by just granting permissions to everything.

Comment: Can you provide more detail than this? This answer is a bit vague and doesn't seem to address the question @SalvatoreD. was asking.

Comment: A bit too vague :) not really helpful